# Ivy.xml file appears to be missing in imported project?

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin, ivy

I'm trying to use the vaadin tutorial.  I imported their addressbook project in their tutorial into eclipse as an existing project.  However, when I import the project is there a way to change it into a vaadin project?  The ivy.xml file is missing and I do not know how to get it.
How would I go about doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: Your pom.xml from the imported project will serve similar purpose as ivy.xml. Can the project be launched from Eclipse?

Comment: For some reason I cannot launch the project from eclipse.  I thought this was due to me not being able to get the ivy.xml.

Comment: What do you get when you try choosing `Run As -> Run on Server` on the imported project?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to this: https://github.com/vaadin/addressbook. This is not an Ivy project and thus will not have an ivy.xml. This is a Maven project, which is sort of competing with Ivy (Ivy uses maven repositories for it's dependency management so not straight up competing, but the xml markup is different). Did some site/readme mention that it should have an ivy.xml?

Anyhow, follow the steps in the readme of that project and should get it running. You don't have to "change it to a vaadin project". Shoot more exact questions on what is going wrong and somebody might have concrete pointers.